# How to break at function in PostMessage/PostThreadMessage while debugging my Release mode binary?

Tags: winapi, debugging, release, mode

My application quits immediately on launching. This happens only on Release mode build. I have symbolized my release mode binary. I am suspecting that some secondary thread is posting WM_QUIT to our queue. I am trying to Break at Function PostThreadMessage with conditional Msg == 0x0012 ( WM_QUIT ). This wont hit. Just to ascertain, I used break at function in PostMessage and SendMessage. No Luck. Can someone please point out if i am missing something here? How do I enable Break at function in case of release mode binaries for WIN32 APIs?

Sincerely,
Subramanian

Comment: You made sure that it isn't a stray WM_QUIT.  Good, now you can look for the real reason.

Comment: Why would you want to check this by breaking at the post? Much easier to check in the message pump. Not that WM_QUIT will be your problem.

Answer (score 1):

This often happens with a missing `break` in your switch/case leading to code falling through to the WM_QUIT handler. The first step I'd take to fix this is to add code to your WM_QUIT handler which outputs the uMsg. This will tell you whether WM_QUIT has really been sent or whether it's just code falling through.

It is possible to breakpoint in Release binaries but the source will not correspond in a nice way to the actual binary so stepping and other debugging features become much less useful.

In terms of setting your breakpoint, set it at `{,,user32.dll}_SendMessageA@16` or `{,,user32.dll}_SendMessageW@16` depending if you're using Unicode or not. However likely this will not be very useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

To set breakpoint use `DebugBreak` API, which would cause the program to crash. Now hit 'Debug' (as appropriate to your OS). It will take you to `DebugBreak` location. It is also possible to debug a release build from withing IDE.

But there is some logical problem with your code than just breakpoint.

Comment: Not entirely true, if you have /DEBUG flag (*not* _DEBUG macro) enabled, it would generate PDB file. And this way Release mode executables can be debugged. I have located bugs like this many times.